# Определение возраста

Tags: php

Как можно определить возраст, сделать проверку на день рождения, и если оно есть или уже прошло сделать возраст +1 ?  можно и просто схему..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используя [DateTime::diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

http://ideone.com/dxX6qu

```
<?php
$birthday="10/10/1905";
$now=new DateTime();
$birthtime=new DateTime($birthday);
$interval = $now->diff($birthtime);
echo $interval->format("Сейчас ему %Y лет\n");
```

Comment: @bazaev05, версия РНР должна быть >= 5.2.0. Читайте на [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.datetime.php)